# Could you explain what this origins from?

Tags: c

```
BOOL MACIsTxReady(void)
{
   return !ReadETHReg(ECON1).ECON1bits.TXRTS;
}
```

is this `ReadETHReg(ECON1)` a function and then what the thing that follows it is?
Excuse my bad English.

Comment: A macro, probably...

Comment: We need to know what libraries or codebase you're using. That appears to be a macro, but we don't know where it's defined.

Comment: Sample: `ReadETHReg()` is a function in http://regard.kfki.hu/temp/MPLAB%20DEMO/Microchip/bsd_tcp_ip/source/ENC28J60.c

Answer (score 2):

read it as this

```
xx = ReadETHReg(ECON1);
yy = xx.ECON1bits;
zz = !yy.TXRTS;
```

you need to explore the definition of ReadETHReg to find out what it returns (probably a struct)

or it might be a macro

Answer (score 0):

Due to operator precedence,

```
return !ReadETHReg(ECON1).ECON1bits.TXRTS;
```

is equivalent to:

```
return !(ReadETHReg(ECON1).ECON1bits.TXRTS);
```

It would seem that `ReadETHReg(ECON1)` returns a `struct` that has a member `ECON1bits`, which in turn is a `struct` that has a member `TXRTS`.

Answer (score 0):

This `ReadETHReg(ECON1)`  is a function that returns a struct. This `.ECON1bits.TXRTS` is accessing a value inside another struct inside the first struct returned.

Like in this code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef bool BOOL;
int ECON1 = 42;

struct S {
    struct {
        bool TXRTS;
    } ECON1bits;
};

struct S ReadETHReg(int val)
{
    struct S ret;
    ret.ECON1bits.TXRTS = val > 40 && val < 50;

    return ret;
}

BOOL MACIsTxReady(void)
{
   return !ReadETHReg(ECON1).ECON1bits.TXRTS;
}
```

Comment: I doesn't. What accepts arguments is the function. The struct is returned by the function